# top value dimension based on sum in SQL

Tags: sql, sum, subquery, top-n

i am having an issue with a query to bring back the top type of transaction for each location:

my table has location varchar, type varchar, transaction int

i've tried the following and get errors:

```
select  
c.location, 
c.type,
sum(c.transaction) as trans_sum
from sales c
group by c.location, c.type
having trans_sum = (
select top 1
c2.type, sum(c2.transaction) as trans_sum2
from sales c2
where c2.location = c.location
group by c2.location, c2.type
order by c2.location, trans_sum2 desc
)
order by c.location, trans_sum desc;
```

Essentially i want the top aggregated value of the transaction column for each type and location.

```
Location Type    Noun
--------------------- 
Atlanta  Channel 750 
Atlanta  Direct  2250 
Atlanta  CC      1850 
Chicago  Channel 625 
Chicago  Direct  1125 
Chicago  CC      612
Dallas   Channel 2183
Dallas   Direct  1165
Dallas   CC      965
```

..................................
The result i am looking for is:
................................

```
    Location Type    Noun
    ---------------------  
    Atlanta  Direct  2250 
    Chicago  Direct  1125
    Dallas   Channel 2183
```

...................................

So, a sql list return with the top location and type aggregated value.  I'd also like the top 3 values for each location/type paring

Comment: Please provide a small data sample (as table, not image) and expected result to assist in answering your question.

Comment: Please also post errors and tag your specific databases (as SQL dialects vary).

Answer (score 0):

remove c2.type in your select

```
select  
c.location, 
c.type,
sum(c.transaction) as trans_sum
from sales c
group by c.location, c.type
having trans_sum = (
select top 1
sum(c2.transaction) as trans_sum2
from sales c2
where c2.location = c.location
group by c2.location, c2.type
order by c2.location, trans_sum2 desc
)
order by c.location, trans_sum desc;
```

Comment: unfortunately, that throws an error "c.transaction is not a valid group by expression"

Answer (score 0):

you probably use sql-server!? If so, I got a first error on using the name "transaction" as a column. This name is already used by the sql server, so I changed it.

Secondly, I don't think you can use the alias "trans_sum" in your having statement. Use sum(c.trans) instead.

This should work:

```
select  
       c.location, 
       c.type,
       sum(c.trans) as trans_sum
 from  foobar c
group by c.location, c.type
having sum(c.trans) = (
         select top 1
                sum(c2.trans) as trans_sum2
           from foobar c2
          where c2.location = c.location
          group by c2.location, c2.type
          order by c2.location, trans_sum2 desc
        )
order by c.location, trans_sum desc;
```

Comment: those aren't the actual column or table names.  Just trying to keep it simple.  That hasn't solved the problem.  Again, still don't have an answer to getting the top1 value for each dimension value using a sum from another column value.

Comment: as i said you can't use "transaction" as a column name. so i changed it to "trans". also i did not have your "sales" table, so i created a "foobar" table. change it to your sales table. if this is not the result you wanted, pleas show us an example what on what data you have and what you want as a result.

Comment: Here is what the data looks like.  I used "Noun" for the transaction for simplicity: Location Type Noun
Atlanta Channel 750
Atlanta Direct 2250
Atlanta CC 1850
Chicago Channel 625
Chicago Direct 1125
Chicago cc 612

Comment: I put your data in your question. Now it is a lot more readable for all of us. As a last thing, could you please tell us now, how your result should look like? Please **update/edit** your question for that.

Comment: Done.  Again, this is one of a variation based on the same set of requirements: two dimensions with an aggregated transaction value.  I want to retrieve the top, top n, or top and bottom values for each of the other column pairs.